# PHP Curl save session

Tags: php, session, curl

This site is HTTPS and I want CURL which open first page, save sessions and than open second page. Is this possible? First page generate language session automatically and I need this session. Without this second page get error.

Error:

> [8] Undefined index: lang
>      File: /var/www/spa-public/public_html/lib/controller.php - Line:8 [2] require_once(lang/.pack.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>      File: /var/www/spa-public/public_html/lib/controller.php - Line:8

My Script:

```
<?php
$postfields = array('lang'=>'ge');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'SECOND_URL');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these fields to curl. then call first one then using same cookie call second one

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "COOKIE.txt"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "COOKIE.txt");
```